# How do I find a message template?

Tags: message-templates

A lifetime member notified me that they received an automated message their membership had expired (typically sent to those with annual memberships). (As they are not dead) this user type should not have received a message that their (lifetime) membership expired.

1. How can I remove "Lifetime" members (as a group) from receiving general (annual) membership expiration notices.
2. How can I find this message template? I looked in "Home › CiviCRM › Administer CiviCRM > Message Templates > User-driven Messages & User-driven Messages" as well as "Headers, Footers, and Automated Messages" and do not find a mailing with the subject header.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Check if you have any Scheduled Reminders based on Memberships and ensure your 'lifetime' Membership Type is excluded from that.

Comment: I do not have my lifetime members included. 
Administration -> Communications -> Scheduled Reminders shows only one scheduled reminder, and this if for our complimentary memberships which do need to renew annually and thus be notified. "Lifetime Members" are *not* selected in the "Entity: Membership" field of the form for that scheduled reminder.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to do the wrong thing. It's not the template you want to change, but the fact that the email is sent at all.

It sounds like your lifetime membership is not correctly configured.

If/when you do want to edit a template, it's there, but in a System messages tab that's not as obvious as it might be.

Answer (score 1):

I have to agree with @Alan-Dixon that it sounds like your lifetime member is set to renew annually whereas there is an option for a "whole lifetime" duration.

I would take a look in your membership types which for me is found in Administer > CiviMember > Membership Types - you can change the duration from there regardless of whether there are any members associated with it.

Comment: Thanks all.

I looked at my "Lifetime" membership type and I do have "duration" set to "1" "Lifetime".

Here are the settings:

Minimum Fee  $: (0)
Contribution Type: (Member Dues) 
Auto-renew Option:  (No auto-renew option)
Duration: (1) (Lifetime)  
Period Type: (rolling)
Fixed Period Rollover Day: (day)
Relationship Type:  
Employee of: (You cannot modify relationship type because there are membership records associated with this membership type.)
Visibility: (admin)
Order: (3)
Enabled? (checked)
Renewal Reminders: (non selected)
Renewal Reminder Day: (blank)